# Black screen attempting to install Ubuntu 22.04 server

Tags: 22.04, uefi

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu Server 22.04 server edition on the Dell Precision 7920 and after I select Try/Install Ubuntu from the menu, the monitor goes black and I receive no signal from my monitor.

Some additional information:

- I'm installing from USB using Rufus using UEFI
- Secure Boot is disabled